# Как ввести количество элементов массива и сам массив с клавиатуры?

Tags: c, массивы, ввод

Пробую следующим образом:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    int i;
    printf("Enter elements", n);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int* a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдает следующую ошибку:

> Error 2   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'int *'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось решить проблему!

Заменил

`int * a = malloc(n * sizeof(int));`

на

`int * a = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));`

И в конце очистил память при помощи `free(a);`

Comment: Поздравляю с решением!

Answer (score 1):

Вы компилируете программу как C++, не как C. Если бы компилировали именно как C, то приведение типа

```
int * a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

оказалось бы ненужным. [Убедитесь сами](http://ideone.com/XTkAMx).

Еще - зачем вам здесь `n`

```
printf("Enter elements", n);
```

если вы его не используете?

Comment: И правда... n не нужно тут... Спасибо!

Comment: С компиляцией в C или в C++ не могу никак разобраться... На парах показали как создавать файл что бы писать на C... Так и создаю...)))

Comment: Обычно достаточно задать ему расширение .c, а не .cpp :) - компиляторы достаточно умные. Бывает и настройка соответствующим параметром командной строки или в свойствах проекта в IDE.

Comment: Спасибо большое!